# FullCalendar - displaying the time only

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've been displaying the time of an appointment in FullCalendar in an alert box and it comes up in this format:

> Mon Dec 06 2010 14:00:00 GMT+0000

This was ok for testing purposes, but now I need it to display the time only, e.g 14:00.
Any idea how to do this from the script below. It's probably a simple solution that i've overlooked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        minTime: 7,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                allDay: false
            }   
            ],
            eventClick: function(event) {
                alert.('Start Time:' + event.start + '<br />End Time:' + event.end + ');
            }
    });

});
```

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: Just noticed a mistake. alert shouldn't have a '.' after it and I'm missing a closing apostrophe. (I was typing this out very quickly) But the solution kgiannakakis provided is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a javascript [date](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php) object, try:

```
alert.('Start Time:' + event.start.getHours() + ':' event.start.getMinutes());
```

You may want to format the above for trailing zeros.